# Video.js youtube video

Tags: youtube, html5-video, video.js

I can't get youtube video to work with video.js

I added in the head :

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
```

Then in the body :

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="360"
  data-setup='{"techOrder":["youtube","html5"],"ytcontrols":false}'>
<source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWjzVHG9T1I" type='video/youtube' />
```

But I have a black div (tested in latest Chrome & FF).
Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this Remy? I'm trying to do the same thing and struggling to find the correct configuration.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet has any figured out a way to make this properly work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pull request referenced above was closed, and somebody else took it over and made it a [plugin](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube), available from the [video.js plugins wiki](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins)

You'll need that (or a similar) plugin to play youtube videos. There's an example of this working for the latest API here: [enabling youtube playback with video.js wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546633/enabling-youtube-playback-with-video-js-wrapper/17584510#17584510)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the Pull Request which add the Youtube Tech feature has not been merged yet.

Though it's getting old now: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/pull/157
I wonder if we could have this soon or not at all :(