# Video.js and YouTube

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I've been unable to get the YouTube plugin working with videoJS. I have what I believe is the latest versions of video.js and vjs.youtube.js. Here's the code I'm using.

```
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script src="vjs.youtube.js"></script>
<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
  controls 
  preload="auto" 
  width="640" 
  height="360" 
  data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], 
  "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7woVTuN8k3c" }'>
</video>
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tanbark/gc5eg/) to a jsfiddle example. Actually, Firefox and Safari are both working for me, but Chrome and IE do not. Are these supported?

Comment: try to create a jsfiddle, it's easier to demonstrate that way. Thanks

Comment: 10-4, here's the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tanbark/ALPSS/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [plugin](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube)  to run YouTube videos in Video.js

See my [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/E69pgesS3aqR8rZwd4Ha?p=preview)

Comment: I thought thats what I was doing. The lower video isn't playing. Could it be my browser?

Comment: It could be your browser, but you probably are not importing the library correctly. However, testing in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an example of getting youtube working on another question:
[enabling youtube playback with video.js wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546633/enabling-youtube-playback-with-video-js-wrapper/17584510#17584510)

Not sure if that helps your issue - but there are a few working examples linked from there that work on chrome for me (linux/osx).