# Playing youtube using videojs, AbortError

Tags: javascript, youtube, video.js

I'm trying to embed youtube video on website that is running on local flask development server. I wanted to use Videojs. Testing with this sample code from https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube

```
 <video
   id="vid1"
   class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
   controls
   autoplay
   width="640" height="264"
   data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type":    "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
 >  
</video>
```

Video doesn't load, when I press play and then stop, firefox console shows this error:

> AbortError: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by
>   the user agent at the user's request.

Firefox is 66.0.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 virtualbox machine on Windows host.
In Chrome on the same machine, video icons are greyed out, no errors on console.

I cannot find description of this error or any related issue with videojs-youtube. What could be the reason of this error?

Comment: Hmmm...you're not showing a complete HTML file of your coding, so we'll probably need that, to completely help you solve this.  That said, I'm assuming you DO have lines to incorporate video.js support script and associated CSS, or else you wouldn't get as far as trying to LOAD the media.  Do you also have at least one line of your javascript, to initialize video-js player?

Comment: [ Nevermind, about 'one line of js to initialize'.  Apparently, per the example, that isn't needed for this usage of video-js. ]  Meanwhile, stay tuned...I'm off trying to create one of these myself, and I'll report back with a comment, once I complete my attempt.

Comment: It appears that the example you are following may now be obsolete, and that there is now a formal 'plugin' for videojs.  This info is detailed here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194379/video-js-youtube-video

Comment: (I have NOT been successful at getting the 'videojs-youtube' PLUGIN to work.) I have a new possible 'theory' : Over past 6 months or so, 'YouTube.com' has morphed into a 'ad-inserting' site.  I wonder if Google is now TRYING to DISCOURAGE devs from using 'embedding' of any alternate 'players' of their content, BECAUSE then their 'ad-insertion' that is builtin to THEIR player doesn't (can't) function. (Note: now they'll SELL you their new 'Youtube-TV' service with the no ads.)  Thus, Google may continue to alter their YouTube infra-structure to keep breaking any 'youtube plugin' that we create.